# Query Build using DataStax Driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have my table as below,

```
create table contact( id uuid primary key, 
                      personName text, 
                      updatedTime timestamp
                    );
```

and trying to execute the below prepare statement,

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE personName IN (:personNameList) " +
                "AND updatedTime > ':startTime' AND  updatedTime < :endTime ALLOW FILTERING;";


        SimpleStatement simpleStatement = SimpleStatement.builder(query)
                                            .setConsistencyLevel(DefaultConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
                                            .build();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cqlSession.prepare(simpleStatement);
        BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind();

        personList = ["John","Alex"];

        boundStatement.setString("startTime", "2020-08-16 14:44:32+0000");  // Issue with setting
        boundStatement.setString("endTime", "2020-08-16 14:60:32+0000");  // Issue with setting
        boundStatement.setList("personNameList", personList, String.class); //  Codec not found for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.util.List<java.lang.String>]

        ResultSet execute = cqlSession.execute(boundStatement);


        // List<Person> personList = // Mapping
```

from 4.7.2 of driver mapping, it is different type to mapping as per my understanding, I couldn't get answer from Google. Any suggestions?

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-processor</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object mapper has changed significantly in the Java driver 4.x, so it requires [setting up of the compile-time processor](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/mapper/config/) to generate auxiliary classes that are necessary for it work.  But you can still use it to convert `Row` object into your POJO, by declaring the method with `GetEntry` [annotation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/mapper/daos/getentity/) in your DAO interface, like this:

```
@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
  @GetEntity
  Person asPerson(Row row);
}
```

But if you're going to use object Mapper, I would recommend to use it for everything - in your case, you can declare a method with the `Query` [annotation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/mapper/daos/query/), and pass parameters for bindings.